# помощь в подключении ImageField к html файлу

Tags: html, django

Здравствуйте!
Не могу найти нормального и полного объяснения в интернете насчет ImageField в Django.

у меня имеется модель:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/blog/%Y/%m/%d')
```

Так же в `settings` прописаны пути для медиа:

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

Но не могу понять как их прикрепить к `html` файлу, чтобы они отображались на страничке

Answer (score 0):

`ImageField` [наследуется](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#ImageField) от `FileField`, поэтому в нём доступен атрибут [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url).

Можно вывести изображение таким образом:

```
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}" />
```

Comment: в логах написано `[10/Oct/2017 17:46:42] "GET /blog/%7B%7B%20post.image.url HTTP/1.1" 200 15631`
Но изображение не появляется

Comment: Вы с программированием-то знакомы?

Comment: Знаком, но это какая-то специфическая ошибка. Так и не решил её

Comment: Если вы не видите в моём коде вывод переменной, то вам требуется обратиться за профессональной помощью к программисту.

Comment: Я следовал Вашим указаниям и они не помогли, к сожалению

Comment: А здесь и не решают проблемы, в основном, здесь дают информацию для дальнейшего решения проблемы.